# Is there any downside to enabling the SHOWPLAN permission to database users in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to enable users to view query execution plans for tuning queries. Is there any downside to enabling the SHOWPLAN permission to database users in SQL Server? I just want to make sure this won't have a negative impact on general performance.

Answer (score 5):

The ability to view query execution plans does not have any performance implications (except may be they will want to improve their query performance when they see how horrible their plans are). As for security concerns, there are a number of [existing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197296/what-are-showplan-permission-security-risks-ms-sql-server) [answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10406/are-there-any-risks-to-granting-users-sql-server-showplan-permission) [addressing that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114786/allowing-non-sysadmin-users-to-see-sql-server-execution-plans).